# How can a character make use of the Communist Propaganda skill in Paranoia?

Tags: paranoia

I am designing a Paranoia one-shot with pre-generated characters. One of the characters belongs to the Communist secret society. Members of the Communist secret society have the mandatory skill Communist Propaganda. How does/can the character use this in the game?

- Can it be used against the other players?
- Is there any way they can use it on NPCs in view of the other players without being immediately gunned down?

It seems that this skill would be relegated to solo interactions with NPCs. Is there any other (amusing) way the player can use it?

For clarity - I am running a classic game, XP version.

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty rare for players to willingly use it, but the best uses of Communist Propaganda I've seen were:

- Confirming identity as a Communist to other Communists.
- Using Communist Propaganda (privately!) to inflict the Communist Propaganda skill onto unwilling clones, and then blackmailing them so that they aren't revealed as traitors to The Computer.

The Communists might also ask members of their secret society to spread Communist Propaganda as one of their goals.

Comment: These were from 2nd Edition games, but this skill isn't appreciably different from XP/2004.